# Uniformly continuous semigroups are analytic

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, uniform-continuity, semigroup-of-operators

I know that every analytic  $C_0$-semigroup is differentiable and the every differentiable semigroup is norm continuous.

I wanted to know where uniform continuity fits in the above picture.

My intuition is that since the generator of a uniformly continuous semigroup is bounded, it is of the form $(e^{tA})_{t\geq 0}$ for some bounded operator $A$, and being the generalization of "exponential" it should certainly be analytic (or at least differentiable). On the other hand, the implication "uniform continuity implies analyticity" seems questionable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A uniformly continuous semigroup is given by the standard exponential of a bounded operator which is the generator. The exponential operator function is analytic on the right half plane $\mathbb{C}^+$ and satisfies the semigroup low. Thus the semigroup is analytic of angle $\pi/2$.